# Linux machine crashing on a daily basis, what does this kernel stacktrace mean?

Tags: crash, core-dump, hang

The crash comes in the form of a total hang. No more control and screen freezes.

I grabbed a stacktrace on this machine using:

`sudo journalctl -f`

The last messages displayed are:

```
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Bad mode in Error handler detected, code 0xbf000002 -- SError
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Internal error: Oops - bad mode: 0 [#3] SMP
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Modules linked in: algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg btrfs xor raid6_pq 8188fu joydev bcmdhd uio_pdrv_genirq uio binfmt_misc sch_fq_codel bnep ip_tables x_tables
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 3469 Comm: smbd Tainted: G      D W       4.4.179 #1
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Hardware name: FriendlyElec NanoPi M4 (DT)
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: task: ffffffc0aedcd400 task.stack: ffffffc047ee8000
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: PC is at 0x7f78af9dfc
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: LR is at 0x7f78af9dd8
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: pc : [<0000007f78af9dfc>] lr : [<0000007f78af9dd8>] pstate: 80000000
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: sp : 0000007f6fbbe370
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x29: 0000007f6fbbe370 x28: 00000055aa9fa870 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x27: 0000007f78afc640 x26: 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x25: 00000055aa9fa898 x24: 0000007f6fbbe4e8 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x23: 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Bad mode in Error handler detected, code 0xbf000002 -- SError
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x22: 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x21: 00000055aa9fa898 x20: 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x19: 0000000000000189 x18: 0000000000000001 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x17: 0000000000000002 x16: 0000000000000002 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x15: 0000000000000000 x14: 002ffa52590473c3 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x13: 0000000063784283 x12: 0000000000000018 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x11: 000000003006b4dc x10: 0000000063784283 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x9 : 003b9aca00000000 x8 : 0000000000000062 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x7 : 0000007f6fbbe448 x6 : 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x5 : 00000000ffffffff x4 : 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x3 : 0000007f6fbbe4e8 x2 : 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x1 : 0000000000000189 x0 : 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Process smbd (pid: 3469, stack limit = 0xffffffc047ee8000)
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: ---[ end trace 5fba866947145e9b ]---
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Bad mode in Error handler detected, code 0xbf000002 -- SError
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Internal error: Oops - bad mode: 0 [#4] SMP
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Modules linked in: algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg btrfs xor raid6_pq 8188fu joydev bcmdhd uio_pdrv_genirq uio binfmt_misc sch_fq_codel bnep ip_tables x_tables
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: CPU: 5 PID: 3471 Comm: smbd Tainted: G      D W       4.4.179 #1
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Hardware name: FriendlyElec NanoPi M4 (DT)
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: task: ffffffc0b72c8000 task.stack: ffffffc047d40000
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: PC is at 0x7f78af9dfc
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: LR is at 0x7f78af9dd8
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: pc : [<0000007f78af9dfc>] lr : [<0000007f78af9dd8>] pstate: 80000000
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: sp : 0000007f7240e370
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x29: 0000007f7240e370 x28: 00000055aa9fa870 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x27: 0000007f78afc640 x26: 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x25: 00000055aa9fa898 x24: 0000007f7240e4e8 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x23: 0000000000000000 x22: 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x21: 00000055aa9fa898 x20: 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x19: 0000000000000189 x18: 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x17: 0000000000000004 x16: 0000000000000002 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x15: 0000000000000000 x14: 00302818e1b6bcc3 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x13: 0000000063784283 x12: 0000000000000018 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x11: 0000000030366a81 x10: 0000000063784283 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x9 : 003b9aca00000000 x8 : 0000000000000062 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x7 : 0000007f7240e448 x6 : 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x5 : 00000000ffffffff x4 : 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x3 : 0000007f7240e4e8 x2 : 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: x1 : 0000000000000189 x0 : 0000000000000000 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: 
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Process smbd (pid: 3471, stack limit = 0xffffffc047d40000)
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: ---[ end trace 5fba866947145e9c ]---
Nov 18 19:42:12  kernel: Internal error: Oops - bad mode: 0 [#5] SMP
```

It seems to happen when accessing the nvme drive heavily, but that might just be associated with the issue. I went in with hdparm and tried to turn off a lot of drive features but the errors persist.

I've also tried changing the clock speeds of the CPU, and changing power supplies. These had little effect

Comment: A very old tainted kernel with no proper backtrace. It's very unlikely anyone will help you.

Comment: Possibly related ? : https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/programmable/articles/000077320.html?wapkw=linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Ok, After seeing Artem's comment I attempted to upgrade my Kernel. However my pi doesn't let me boot into GRUB for some reason so I ran boot-repair. I spent a while on this but boot repair kept complaining that I had a shortage of disk space.</strike>

I had 30MB free, I have things partitioned in a bad way so there isn't much space to work with, but I was able to free another 700MB and since then the crashes have vanished.

Turns out it's the nvme driver after all. Using usb instead fixed this